# Shell scripting - save to a file, so the file will always have the last 10 values added

Tags: shell

I found myself quite stomped. I am trying to output data from a script to a file.

Altho I need to keep only the last 10 values, so the append won't work.

The main script returns one line; so I save it to a file. I use tail to get the last 10 lines and process them, but then I get to the point where the file is too big, due the fact that I continue to append lines to it (the script output a line every minute or so, which bring up the size of the log quite fast.

I would like to limit the number of writes that I do on that script, so I can always have only the last 10 lines, discarding the rest.

I have thought about different approaches, but they all involve a lot of activity, like create temp files, delete the original file and create a new file, with just the tail of the last 10 entry; but it feels so un-elegant and very amateurish.

Is there a quick and clean way to query a file, so I can add lines until I hit 10 lines, and then start to delete the lines in chronological order, and add the new ones on the bottom?

Maybe things are easier than what I think, and there is a simple solution that I cannot see.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In general, it is difficult to remove data from the start of a file.  The only way to do it is to overwrite the file with the tail that you wish to keep.  It isn't that ugly to write, though.  One fairly reasonable hack is to do:

```
{ rm file; tail -9 > file; echo line 10 >> file; } < file
```

This will retain the last 9 lines and add a 10th line.  There is a lot of redundancy, so you might like to do something like:

```
append() { test -f $1 && { rm $1; tail -9 > $1; } < $1; cat >> $1; }
```

And then invoke it as:

```
echo 'the new 10th line' | append file
```

Please note that this hack of using redirecting input to the same file as the later output is a bit fragile and obscure.  It is entirely possible for the script to be interrupted and delete the file!  It would be safer and more maintainable to explicitly use a temporary file.

Comment: Thanks William, I thought that it was really convoluted to remove lines from the top, so I guess the quick and dirty way is to move just the last 10 lines of the file in a new file every time. Altho it feels quite a waste of resources to do so every time that I get a new line.

Comment: I would agree that it is a waste of resources.  If you only want to see the last 10 lines, it would be much cleaner to filter them out when you view them and only rewrite the file when it gets closer to a much larger size.